# SolrSynonymParser one word in two "Equivalent synonyms" lines

Tags: solr, lucene, synonym

If I use a text file to define synonyms in Solr/Lucene like this:

```
foo, bar, goo
abc, bar, xyz
```

The word `bar` is in both lines.

Does this mean Solr treats all terms to be synonyms, so that it equals this one line?

```
foo, bar, goo, abc, xyz
```

I only found this document, please leave a comment if you know a better explanation of the file format: [Equivalent synonyms](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_3_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/synonym/SolrSynonymParser.html)

Comment: Related Article of David Argüello Sánchez https://medium.com/empathyco/synonyms-in-solr-i-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-efe8e437a940

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this mean Solr treats all terms to be synonyms,
> so that it equals this one line?

If you search for the word "bar" that is in both lines the answer is yes. You can confirm this via the Analysis screen by looking at output for the SynonymsGraphFilter

[image]

But if you search for the word "foo" (that only shows in one line) then only the synonyms "bar", and "goo" will be used.

Comment: The answer seems mostly correct from the documentation. There is a twist based on the presence of the 'expand' parameter in how the values in each line will be used.